# How can I scroll through a playlist for audio

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm attempting to make a playlist scrollable, but have not had any success. I appreciate any direction. I'm dynamically reading .mp3 files from a file, and displaying the mp3 names inside a div. If I add more than 6 files the div area increases so the mp3 names are displayed, but it extends beyond/over the controls. I want to make the list scrollable after 6 names, if possible. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
...
<!-- Create out audio controls -->
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" controls="controls" type="audio/mpeg" ontimeupdate="displayTime(this)">
<source src="data/song1.mp3">song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" > 
Unsupported audio format!
</audio>

<!--Audio in our Playlist-->
<div id="Playlist">
<ul class="playlist">
<?php $files = scandir( "data/" ); ?>
<?php foreach ( $files as $file )
if ( $file != '.' && $file != '..' )
     echo "<li audiourl=\"data/$file\"></li>"; ?>

</ul>
</div>
...
```

CSS:

```
...

.playlist
{   
position: relative;
background:#666;
top: 295px;
left: 730px;
width:500px;
padding:15px;

}


#Playlist ul.playlist 
{
position: relative;
overflow: auto;

}
...
```

JS:

```
...
var playList = document.getElementsByClassName('Playlist');
playList.scrollTop = 400;
...
```

Comment: You want to use Javascript, not "HTML5", which is the most misused term I have ever heard.

Comment: @Rob I thought I was using Javascript, at least I am attempting ....

Comment: Your title asked how to do this in "HTML5".

Comment: Yes, the base is HTML5 (DOM), and I'm just using PHP and Javascript to do certain things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is more PHP based, but:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php 
        $chunky = array_chunk ( $files , 6);
        foreach ($chunky as $array) {
            echo '<div class="item"><ul>';
                foreach ($array as $name){
                    echo '<li>' . $name . '</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul></div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Could you use `array_chunk($files, 6)` to split files into groups of six, and then do something like the above to output them into the markup for the Bootstrap carousel? (https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/).

EDIT: code example here https://eval.in/692526